# Why does this sprite spawn at 0,0 when I change it when it spawns?

Tags: godot, gdscript

### Background

I'm making a mining game in Godot. I'm doing procedural generation and spawning chunks based on player position.

### Problem

The issue I have is that the emerald vein is at global position (0,0) but I change it in the spawning script. I need to get the global position to use it in the seed, so I can get a value of 1 or 0 to get a stone or emerald block. Because it is 0,0 each chunk loads like this:
[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWZQp.jpg)

```
var rand = round(abs(chunksettings.noise.get_noise_2d(self.global_position.x + (x * offset),self.global_position.y + (y * offset)))*3)
```

I have mining veins to load as chunks later on. These mining veins spawn blocks within them.

This scene is instanced in the main scene.

### Code

```
extends Node2D


#offset between chunks
var offset = 48

#preloading chunk settings
export var load_x = 20
export var load_y = 20

#all the veins to spawn
var stone_vein = preload("res://Scenes/veins/Stone vein.tscn")
var emerald_vein = preload("res://Scenes/veins/Emerald vein.tscn")

func _ready():
    for x in load_x:
        
        for y in load_y:
            var emerald_vein_inst = emerald_vein.instance()
            add_child(emerald_vein_inst)
            emerald_vein_inst.position2d.global_position.x = x * offset
            emerald_vein_inst.position2d.global_position.y = y * offset
            emerald_vein_inst.global_position.x = x * offset
            emerald_vein_inst.global_position.y = y * offset

func getrandomnumber():
    pass
```

Here is the code for the mining veins:

```
extends Node2D

onready var selfnoise = OpenSimplexNoise.new()
onready var chunksettings = $"/root/ChunkSettings"
onready var position2d = $Position2D
var emerald_block = preload("res://Scenes/Blocks/Emerald block.tscn")
var stone_block = preload("res://Scenes/Blocks/Stone_Block.tscn")
var offset = 16
var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.new()

func _ready():
    selfnoise.seed = chunksettings.noise.seed
    selfnoise.octaves = chunksettings.noise.octaves
    selfnoise.persistence = chunksettings.noise.persistence
    selfnoise.lacunarity = chunksettings.noise.lacunarity
    gen_vein()
    
func gen_vein():
    for x in 3:
        for y in 3:
            var inst_stone = stone_block.instance()
            var inst_emerald = emerald_block.instance()
            var inst = inst_stone
            var rand = round(abs(chunksettings.noise.get_noise_2d(self.global_position.x + (x * offset),self.global_position.y + (y * offset)))*3)
            print(rand)
            if rand == 1:
                inst = inst_emerald
            elif rand == 0:
                inst = inst_stone
            print(self.global_position)
            add_child(inst)
            inst.position.x = offset * x
            inst.position.y = offset * y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed one part of my code and made this work. When it spawns the node, it runs the node script and *then* changes its position. So, what I've changed was the order of when it spawns.

```
func _ready():
    for x in load_x:
        
        for y in load_y:
            var emerald_vein_inst = emerald_vein.instance()
            emerald_vein_inst.global_position.x = x * offset
            emerald_vein_inst.global_position.y = y * offset
            add_child(emerald_vein_inst)
```

Instead of:

```
func _ready():
    for x in load_x:
        
        for y in load_y:
            var emerald_vein_inst = emerald_vein.instance()
            add_child(emerald_vein_inst)
            emerald_vein_inst.position2d.global_position.x = x * offset
            emerald_vein_inst.position2d.global_position.y = y * offset
            emerald_vein_inst.global_position.x = x * offset
            emerald_vein_inst.global_position.y = y * offset
```

Someone on Reddit helped me ([details](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/qj4m44/global_position_prints_00/)).